# How to pass YAML boolean into HAML

Tags: ruby, haml, yaml

Is it possible to pass a YAML boolean into HAML? I've attempted a couple ways, but can't seem to get it to understand, short of just matching the text.

Here's the YAML boolean:

```
---
show_banner: true
---
```

I've tried explicitly matching the boolean and also loosely matching it in HAML.

```
- if "#{page.show_banner}" == true

- if "#{page.show_banner}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What context is this HAML in? How are you passing in parameters?

Without knowing more, I assume you could do this:

```
- if page.show_banner
```

Your use of quotation marks is changing the parameter to a string.

Comment: Well, that was simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have had luck using a [Ruby object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html) as an intermediary, like in the code below.

```
require 'YAML'
require 'HAML'

a = ('ShowBanner: false').to_yaml
puts a
b = YAML::load(a)
puts b
c = Haml::Engine.new(b)
d = c.render(b)
puts d
```